# Using C[1] in RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

After solving this equation $ a+b e^{\theta  (-\rho )}+\rho =0 $ for $\rho$, I am having trouble plotting the region in terms of $C[1]$. The region plot works if I change this $C[1]$ to other variable.

```
Reduce[\[Rho] + a + b E^(-\[Rho] \[Theta]) == 0, \[Rho]]

(* \[Rho] == (-a \[Theta] + 
  ProductLog[C[1], -b E^(a \[Theta]) \[Theta]])/\[Theta] *)

Module[{\[Theta] = 1, k = 0},
 RegionPlot[
  Re[(-a \[Theta] + 
     ProductLog[k, -b E^(a \[Theta]) \[Theta]])/\[Theta]] < 0, {a, -6,
    6}, {b, -6, 6}]]
```

[image]

I would like to plot the equations without manually modifying the output of the Reduce function. I tried changing Module with With/Block. Still the same issue. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: [`C`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html) is a built-in symbol that represents a constant. You would need to use something like `ReplaceAll` to do what you have tried in the second example.

Comment: As suggested by CA Trevillian this worked:  Module[{\[Theta] = 1},
  RegionPlot[
   Re[(-a \[Theta] + 
       ProductLog[C[1], -b E^(a \[Theta]) \[Theta]])/\[Theta] /. {C[
        1] -> 0}] < 0, {a, -6, 6}, {b, -6, 6}]]                 Thanks.

Comment: But `ProductLog` is a complex function. Do you want to find the real solution about `ρ + a + b E^(-ρ θ) == 0` ?

Comment: @ cvgmt, I am not sure what you mean. I was reading [this paper](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/transactions/systems/2010/89-477.pdf) and tried to replicate Figure 4 in section 2.2.2. I work with mostly Delay Differential Equations and this C[1] had been bugging me in my other equations too. I have some transcendental equations which I would like to solve but Mathematica is not giving me the output. I am  planning to post the equation as a new question soon. Thanks. For now, this trick works.